# Rails 3 and update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am moving an application from Rails 2.2.2 to Rails 3. I have a form that is used to update a user's info that was fully functional in Rails 2 but breaks in Rails 3

When the form is submitted, a method is called that creates the user object and then tries to do the update like this:

```
if @user.update_attributes params[:user] ## line 126
```

Then the controller throws this exception:

```
undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xacfc178>

in: app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:126:in `save_user'
```

So it looks like ActiveRecord in Rails 3 is returning a different type of object? One that doesn't inherit update_attributes? How do I fix this?

Here is the full controller method in question:

```
def save_user
@needs_password_gen = "YES"
@user = B2bUser.where("id = ?",params[:id])

@needsAPICredentials = false

##### Make sure thay gave us an email address
if !params[:user][:email] || !validEmailAddress(params[:user][:email].to_s)
  flash[:warning] = "Valid email address is required."
  redirect_to :controller => "admin/edit_user/#{@user.id}" and return
end

@user.first.update_attributes params[:user]
```

end

THANKS

Comment: can u paste the code from the controller? instead of single line.

Comment: `update_attributes` works with a single record, not a collection, how is @user defined?

Comment: try @user.first.update_attributes params[:user]

Comment: @SachinR this will probably work but it doesn't make sense to write this... \@user is supposed to be a User object.

Comment: What is the method you are using to retrieve the  @user. Is it a where or a find?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681371/update-fail-undefined-method-update-attributes-for-activerecordrelation

Comment: added the "save" method from the controller in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your @user object may be an array. You are probably using :where to query and are forgetting to pop it off the array. Try this:

```
@user.first.update_attributes params[:user]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It returns this: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, company, email, username, password, api_password, api_username, send_email_reminders, is_admin I updated my question such that it now includes the controller method where the error is happening

Comment: Make sure all the fields in your hash are opened up with attr_accessible in your User model. You can also just edit the incoming hash and update_attribute on selected fields.